# Caching bitmap Android

Tags: android, caching, bitmap, store

What is the best way of caching Bitmaps if my min sdk is api lvl 8? I have a downloaded Bitmap which I would like to save, I can also get a type of hash for the image. Is it OK to just write it to a normal file anywhere if i fix the permissions, say like this?

```
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best way to download and cache images is use Volley library. It's really easy and comfortable. There are a lot of different examples in the Internet but at first I suggest you to watch [IO video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo) . And then look for code examples (`BitmapLruCache` - is used directly for caching) (e.g. [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-volley-library-example.html) or [here](http://blog.wittchen.biz.pl/asynchronous-loading-and-caching-bitmaps-with-volley/))

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library. It will do the caching, loading from url and other things by itself.